# How do I add more options to the post-new.php page?

Tags: php, posts, screen-options

Some themes have options such as 'enabling or disabling the sidebar', etc, on the post-new.php page. How can I do those (without plugins, I'm making a theme from scratch)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic is vast, so I'm not going to discuss every detail. In WordPress, there is a concept called **meta box**. Publish, Page Attributes, Featured Image these all are meta boxes. And the good thing is you can create custom meta box. To know how to do that you have to be familiar with [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) function which is one of the many meta box API functions and also the [`add_meta_boxes`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes) action hook. Here's an article which will help you to get started https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-custom-meta-boxes-to-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I needed. I couldn't understand which function & API I needed to use. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that. if you think my answer is the answer you were expecting then you can accept the answer, it'll encourage me to help others more :D